# How to make a dictionary using separate key and value array

Tags: python, dictionary

How to make a dictionary by using separate arrays of key and value.
e.g I have:

```
      a = np.array([10,20,30])
      b = np.array([100,200,300])
```

I want a dictionary like this:

```
      dic = {10:100,20:200,30:300}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) can be constructed from a list of tuples, you can construct that list of tuples using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> dict(zip(a,b))
{10: 100, 20: 200, 30: 300}
```

If you don't want to create the intermediate list (say you have two very big lists) it's better to use an iterator such as [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> dict(izip(a,b))
{10: 100, 20: 200, 30: 300}
```

Comment: From the link I've provided: *This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables.*

Comment: Is dict a function here?